# Form Submit in my code does not work on webbrowser control C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser, webbrowser-control

This a html code in site that i want to use it in my web browser control C# :

```
<form name="frmWorkBookPrintTerm" action="WorkBookPrintTerm.asp" target="_blank" method="post">
<hr width="90%">
<input type="Hidden" name="strTermCode" value="912">
<input type="Hidden" name="strStudentCode" value="896325605">
<input type="Button" onclick="javascript:document.frmWorkBookPrintTerm.submit();" value="...">
<hr width="90%">
</form>
```

But It is not working. When i want to go ".../WorkBookPrintTerm.asp" directly website says you did illegal job and otherwise web browser control is not working.

Thank You.

Comment: You said _"website says you did illegal job"_ .  Is that really what the message says?

Comment: Yes. And Log me out .:!

Comment: Website is a university student management site and that page is my term workbook.

Comment: This looks like a CSRF from your crafted page to their site. Could possibly work, however, they could prevent such operations with some form of cross-site antiforgery tokens. That would explain the "illegal job".

Comment: Can you post a code how you're doing form submit?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter : I don't do that. web browser should do

Comment: You said "going to /WorkBookPrintTerm.asp directly". But you're not going there directly - you're building a form and clicking the button to go there, correct?

Comment: No. This code is code of the site that i want to use it in web browser control c#. but when i click submit button it shows me a blank.
when i go to the page directly it shows me error.